# HTML button calling function from js file

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button calling function 'a':

```
<button id = "btn" type="button"
          onclick="a();">someText</button>
```

This function's showing and hiding an element:

```
 <p id="text" style= "display:none;">
Text.</p>
```

Function:

```
    function a() {

  var b= 0;      
  if (b === 0) 
  {
    document.getElementById('text').style.display='block';
    document.getElementById('btn').innerHTML="changed text";
    b = 1;
  }
  else
  {
    document.getElementById('text').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('btn').innerHTML="someText";
    b = 0;
  } 
}
```

It worked until I moved this function to a separate file 'x.js'.
I attached this file to my `index.html`:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="x.js"></script>
```

What's wrong with it? What should I do to make it work?

Comment: Any console errors? Also  var b= 0;  will make the script do the same each time.

Comment: Nothing is wrong with what you've described in the question. The problem must be something to do with something you haven't mentioned. Maybe you just got the URL wrong.

Comment: @Quentin - "nothing is wrong"? Half the function as it is shown will never execute.

Comment: @Igor — Well, nothing to do with the *change* described that is supposed to have broken it.

Comment: By the way your  toggle can be written like this `var changed = false;

function a() {
  document.getElementById('text').style.display = changed ? 'block' : 'none';
  document.getElementById('btn').innerHTML = changed ? "changed text" : "someText";
  changed = !changed;
}`

Answer (score 0):

`var b= 0;` should be defined before the function and be global

```js
var b = 0;

function a() {
  if (b === 0) {
    document.getElementById('text').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('btn').innerHTML = "changed text";
    b = 1;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('text').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('btn').innerHTML = "someText";
    b = 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>The Steve Barrett Collection</title>
</head>
<body>
  <button id="btn" type="button" onclick="a()">someText</button>
  <p id="text" style="display:none;">
    Text.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: in your code onclick="a();" does not need ; and   var b= 0; 
should be define befor the function and be global

Comment: The semicolon is irrelevant and add your comment to the answer

Comment: i do not have 50 reputation to comment

Comment: Add the comment you made to your answer instead of commenting on your own answer